# Storing map coordinate in to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I look many sample code for storing data into sqlite but it work .How I store this 
I am trying to add the the `(newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude)`
into sqlite database .
I find this `(newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude)`
from here

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation)
    {


        // make sure the old and new coordinates are different
        if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
            (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
        {    
            //I think Here will my sqlite query for storing the newLocation.coordinate.latitude and  newLocation.coordinate.longitude 
         //But I dont know how i store this location into the sqlite database.

         }
     }
}
```

How can i do .Can anyone help me out from this.

Comment: do u know how to use sqlite? if no means study this http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: I knows how to use the sqlite But the location is coming dynamically .And I am getting problem that's way ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this statement....

sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

Comment: @harish, You can create two columns in db for latitude and longitude and bind those values seperately using the method above.

Comment: you can refer this link on how to add data in database
http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-adding-data.html

Comment: can Implement this method into the if((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude !=newLocation.coordinate.latitude)&&(oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
 { const char *sql = "insert into location(long, lati) Values(?, ?)";}

Answer (score 0):

using coredata would be much easier,other wise try storing into a plist.

Comment: No it's compulsory to store this location into the sqlite database

Comment: [link](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-adding-data.html)   perhaps this would help you

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple in my view, just made a function open sqlite db in it and then write this code

```
NSString *update = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (longitude, latitude) VALUES ('32.333, 74.6655');"];



char * errorMsg;

    if (sqlite3_exec (database, [update UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating tables: %s", errorMsg);   
    }

    NSLog(@"Location Inserted");
```

`